# Exceptions while running fat jar of kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying out wordcount example for learning kafka streams. Below is the code used. I have created a fat jar from the project and started to produce messages to topic `word-count-input1` and am fetching the output from `word-count-output1`. But when I run the fat jar am seeing exception - `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to deserialize value for record.`

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"word-count-example");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"127.0.0.1:9092");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass());

    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    // 1. Stream from kafka

    KStream<String,String> wordcountInput = builder.stream("word-count-input1");

    // 2. map values to lower case

   KTable<String, Long> wordcount = wordcountInput.mapValues(value -> value.toLowerCase())

                                   // 3. split by space on values
                                    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(" ")))

                                   // 4. Create  a key to apply a key, so the word itself is a key

                                    .selectKey((ignoredKey,words) -> words)

                                    // 5. Group it by key

                                    .groupByKey()

                                    // 6. count occurences, add a column name - counts

                                    .count("counts");

   // Since the StreamsConfig was set to String and String, its mandatory to specify the Serdes o/p which is String and Long in our case
    wordcount.to(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long(),"word-count-output1");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, properties);
    streams.start();
    System.out.println("Topology is " + streams.toString());
```

**Exception:**

```
INFO stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Shutting down (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:1040)
INFO Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:972)
INFO stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Removing all active tasks [0_0, 1_0, 0_1, 1_1, 0_2, 1_2] (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:1407)
INFO stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Removing all standby tasks [] (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:1421)
INFO stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Stream thread shutdown complete (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:1072)
WARN stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Unexpected state transition from RUNNING to DEAD. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:978)
Exception in thread "word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to deserialize value for record. topic=word-count-input1, partition=0, offset=0
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.deserialize(SourceNodeRecordDeserializer.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:84)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:464)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:650)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:556)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
INFO stream-client [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN. (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams:229)
INFO stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Informed thread to shut down (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:900)
WARN stream-thread [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a-StreamThread-1] Unexpected state transition from DEAD to PENDING_SHUTDOWN. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:978)
INFO stream-client [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a] Stopped Kafka Streams process. (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams:514)
INFO stream-client [word-count-example-052c3c3e-8dfd-40e7-8b5b-7ee06e3af96a] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to NOT_RUNNING. (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams:229)
```

Setup is that am running a zookeeper and 3 brokers on a linux VM. Could someone please suggest ?

Comment: what version of kafka pls?

Answer (score 2):

You did specify `LongDeserializer` for the `VALUE_DESERIALIZER? The actual error is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
```

So it seems, that your value is not a 8 byte long value. I assume, your value is actually a string for the input topic? So you need so specify the correct deserializer that matches your data.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your Ktable to this should fix it:

```
KTable<String, Long> wordcount = source
                .flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
                        return Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split(" "));
                    }
                })
                .groupBy(new KeyValueMapper<String, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(String key, String value) {
                        return value;
                    }
                })
                .count("Counts");
```